# UserPrincipal GetGroups very slow on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a method to get user's groups on Windows 2008 AD.

```
using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, login, pwd))
{
    using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName))
    {
        if (foundUser != null)
        {
            var grs = foundUser.GetGroups(domainContext);
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The batch works perfectly on Windows server 2003 and XP but i have a very slow response on windows server 2008 with this line:

```
foundUser.GetGroups(domainContext);
```

- Windows Server 2003 and XP : the call takes 100ms
- Windows Server 2008 : the call takes 2500ms

Can you help me with this problem ?

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a Domain Issue going on there do both servers access the same AD Server..? also are you doing this with .net `3.5 or 4.0`

Comment: Hello,the same AD is reached and i'm using 3.5

Comment: I wonder if there is an actual issue with that newer server but it's really hard to tell especially on a forum like this